# How to access from child checkbox to child class in different parent divs?

Tags: html, css, checkbox, sass

How can i rotate all 3 pictures on click on checkbox?

I am trying with `~` but it only affects on the image where checkbox is.

HTML:

```
<div class="img-wrapper">
  <img class="img" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300" />
</div>

<div class="img-wrapper">
  <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" id="rotate">
  <label class="label-checkbox" for="rotate">Rotate</label>

  <img class="img" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300" />
</div>

<div class="img-wrapper">
  <img class="img" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300" />
</div>
```

SCSS:

```
.checkbox:checked {
        ~ .img {
          transform: rotate(180deg);
        }
    }
```

Comment: you need a script for it. even SCSS does not have the abiltiy to select elements which are not siblings or decendents.

Comment: ... or move the checkbox before all those wrapper divs. (The label can stay where it is.) And then you need to select the sibling divs of the checkbox first, and then rotate the images inside those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we have [`:has()`](https://caniuse.com/?search=has) pseudo selector today, it might be

```css
.something:has(input:checked) img {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

As far as we haven't yet, you should lift up the checkbox for it

```
<input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" id="rotate">

<div class="img-wrapper">
  <img class="img" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300" />
</div>

<div class="img-wrapper">
  <label class="label-checkbox" for="rotate">Rotate</label>

  <img class="img" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300" />
</div>

<div class="img-wrapper">
  <img class="img" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300" />
</div>
```

Then you can select `<img>`s using

```
input:checked ~ .img-wrapper > img {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

And you can draw a custom checkbox by hiding original `<input>` and styling on the `<label>`

Answer (score 2):

You could do it with javascript, something like this:

```
if ($("#rotate").is(':checked')) {
    $(".img-wrapper img").css("transform", "rotate(180deg)");
}
```

or

```
if ($("#rotate").is(':checked')) {
    $(this).parent().find("img").css("transform", "rotate(180deg)");
}
```

Other option  `:has`

https://caniuse.com/?search=%3Ahas

Comment: you could greatly improve your answer with a working [repro] -> `<>` or `Crtl + M`

Comment: Thanks, but i need to do this only with CSS